# pointer to std::map trouble

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap, std

Please consider the following code where I get an access violation inserting values into a std::map object.  Not sure why.  The code as you see it uses

```
std::map<int, int>
```

however, I initially tried

```
std::map<int, MSGTYPE>
```

with the same resulting access violation. (I know enums are INTs).

```
// a common include file has this
// common.h

enum MSGTYPE
{
  MSG_R1,
  MSG_A1,
  MSG_L1,
  MSG_S1,
  MSG_S2
};

typedef std::map<int, int> SYSMsgMap;

typedef struct _MYOBJ
{
  int x1;
  int x2;
  SYSMsgMap XFerMap;
}MYOBJ;
```

My use of these structures looks like so:

```
MYOBJ *cMYOBJ::AddNetwork(cvnet *net)
{
MYOBJ *ob;

  ob = new MYOBJ();

  // initialization code removed for this post/brevity

  BuildMsgMap(ob->XFerMap);

  // rest removed for this post/brevity
}

void cMYOBJ::BuildMsgMap(std::map<int, int> &mm)
{

  mm.clear();

  switch(NETTYPE)
  {
    case 1: 
      mm[ 1] = MSG_R1;  <-- Access violation here!
      mm[ 2] = MSG_A1;
      mm[ 4] = MSG_L1;
      mm[16] = MSG_S1;
      mm[32] = MSG_S2;
    break;

 // rest removed...
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @Amend, so please stop wasting my time.

Comment: I don't see a reason for that failure. I suspect some commented-out code might corrupt this object. -- To clarify Armen's comment: One can see a big influence of plain-C style in this C++. In particular you can declare `struct MYOBJ { ... };` (without typedef and trailing name) with exactly same effect in C++. You couldn't do that in C.

Comment: What is NETTYPE?  The implementation isn't listed, but some implementations don't do a good job of pinpointing the exact crash spot.

Comment: @CygnusX1:  Understand.  This is inherited code, not all mine.  However, I too don't understand the problem hence me asking here.  The debugger is traces the AV to the above mentioned line.

@David: NETTYPE is an INT

Comment: How does `cMYOBJ::BuildMsgMap` get called? What's the context?

Comment: What's under "// initialization code removed for this post/brevity
"? I suspect the error may be somewhere under it. But if you have a lot of code in there, this may end up in a long debugging. Maybe try commenting out parts of your code, until AV does not appear anymore (at least at that spot).

Comment: Is this a multithread application?

Comment: @Eric : Unrelated to your question, but `_MYOBJ` is an illegal type name in C++. Quoting the C++03 standard, §17.4.3.1.2/1: "*Each name that contains a double underscore (`__`) or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use.*"

Comment: @CygnusX1:  The code that has been removed is simple default settings of the type  ob->Var1 = 5, ob->Var2 = 6, etc...   I changed the BuildMsgMap to void cMYOBJ::BuildMsgMap(MYOBJ &) which did not work (same error) and I tried moving the content of BuildMsgMap up into the body of AddNetwork and still get same error.

Comment: @ildjarn:  Thank you for your FYI.  I was not aware of that detail.  I will say, in response, that other code has similar definitions throughout and it has been this way for years.  The code base is 10 years old and so I sort of have a mix of C and C++ style within.

Comment: I would guess the bug is in code that you have removed. The code as written here would work, I think. Try to post a complete, minimal example that you've run and which demonstrates the error (the above code is missing braces, so I know you haven't run it exactly as-is).

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't `ob` get accidentally cleared with `memset(ob, sizeof(MYOBJ), 0)` somewhere after `ob = new MYOBJ;` and before the call to `BuildMsgMap()`?

(Since the code is legacy and since `memset` trick is often used in C.)

Comment: Funny you mention this.  You are in fact right!  Before I posted this, I did in fact have a memset right after the new that is now commented out.  I also changed the new MYOBJ to new MYOBJ();

Answer (score 0):

i think since mm is a reference to the mm[0], and that is all the memory allocation you've got
so for mm[1] you need to do an insert.

or you'd like to do

```
ob = new MYOBJ[33];//since you have indexed mm[32] in the next function
```

hope this helps

Comment: index operator of map is a T&, not pair<K,T>. Also the compiler would pick that up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting an access violation because MYOBJ has no constructor defined, and therefore the constructor of SYSMsgMap is not getting called. Add an empty no-argument constructor to MYOBJ and see if it changes things, e.g.

```
typedef struct _MYOBJ
{
  _MYOBJ() {}
  int x1;
  int x2;
  SYSMsgMap XFerMap;
}MYOBJ;
```